# Dropdown Options Based on Previous Selection

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I'm hoping this is a simple solution. I am trying to make the first drop down determine the options available for the second. In my database, each flavor for the drink type has "type_id" column set as an integer (i.e. 1,2,3). The integers are meant to reflect the category in which they belong. Is it possible/make sense to base the available options for the second drop down off of the "type_id" that I determined?

I was hoping to accomplish this by using PHP, but I am not opposed to jQuery. I am not very well versed in one over the other. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
 <?php
require "db-connect.php";
$dtype = "SELECT name FROM drinktype";
$typedata = mysqli_query($connection, $dtype);

  echo "<select id='slctType'>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($typedata) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($typedata)) {

echo "<option value='{".$row['name']."}'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
} 
echo "</select>";

$dflavor = "SELECT type_id,name FROM drinkflavor";
$flavordata = mysqli_query($connection, $dflavor);


  echo "<select id='slctFlavor' ";
if (mysqli_num_rows($flavordata) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flavordata)) {

echo "<option value='{".$row['name']."}'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
} 
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sample code for fetching the city according to their state. I have do that code with ajax, jquery and php. I think you have similar type of requirement. Please try below code concept for your requirement.

```
$(document).on('change','#state',function () {
    $('#city').remove();
    if($(this).val() != 'none')
    {
        var state_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'page.php',
            data: { state_id: state_id },
            success: function (city_response) {
                if(city_response == '')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var city = '<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">';
                    city += '<option value="-----">Please select any City</option>';
                    $.each(city_response, function (ck, cv) {
                        city += '<option value="' + cv['city_id'] + '">' + cv['city_name'] + '</option>';
                    });
                    city += '</select>';
                    $("#city_div").css('display', 'block');
                    $('#cities').append(city);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        $("#city_div").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```